# Init subclass does not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, init, skspritenode

I want to spawn spritenodes to screen by a subclass, but it doesn't show up on screen. Somebody know what I do wrong?

**Subclass**

```
@implementation Seagull

-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _atlas = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"Seagull"];
        _seagull = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[_atlas textureNamed:@"Seagull1"]];
        _seagull.size = CGSizeMake(156.8, 115.4);

        NSArray *flyFrames = @[[_atlas textureNamed:@"Seagull1"],
                               [_atlas textureNamed:@"Seagull2"]];

        _flyAnimation = [SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction animateWithTextures:flyFrames timePerFrame:0.15 resize:NO restore:NO]];

        [_seagull runAction:_flyAnimation];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

**Subclass object created**

```
-(Seagull *)spawnSeagull
{
    Seagull *seaGull = [[Seagull alloc] init];
    seaGull.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width * 0.5, self.size.height * 0.5);
    NSLog(@"seagull postion.x = %f && position.y = %f", seaGull.position.x, seaGull.position.y);
    [self addChild:seaGull];

    return seaGull;
}
```

**Added to the scene in viewDidLoad**

```
[self spawnSeagull];
```

Comment: You're returning a seagull in `spawnSeagull` but you don't show that being assigned to any object in `[self spawnSeagull];`. Did you mean to write `_seagull = [self spawnSeagull];`?

Comment: Did you get error with your code? Because I guess in your GameScene, no method named `spawnSeagull` was declared.

Comment: @timgcarlson Hmm. What do you mean with not being assigned to any object? Do I need to create an SKSpriteNode object in GameScene and assign it the Seagull class object in spawnSeagull or Didmovetoview?

Comment: @WangYudong spawnSeagull is declared in gamescene yeah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make a mistake in creating a **property** `SKSpriteNode` (_seagull) in an **class** `SKSpriteNode` (Seagull).

In your `init` method, you initialize `_seagull` as an `SKSpriteNode`, but when to spawn seagull, all you do is just creating and adding an instance of class `Seagull` to the scene, nothing to do with `_seagull` which actually contains the texture of a seagull. To fix that, you need to return `seaGull.seagull` in `spawnSeagull`, which is not the best practice I'm afraid.

However, there are still several places need to fix in your code.

In `spawnSeagull`:

- `CGPointMake(self.size.width * 0.5, self.size.height * 0.5)` is wrong because you won't get the half size of the scene in this way.
- You should call `[self addChild:seaGull]` in your **GameScene**, because you want to add it to a scene, not to a subclass of an `SKSpriteNode`.

In `viewDidLoad` (`didMoveToView` recommended):

- As @timgcarlson commented, you need an object to assign it the return result of `spawnSeagull`.

I add the complete code below:

Remove `init`, and add a class method in the subclass,

```
+ (Seagull *)spawnSeagull
{
    SKTextureAtlas *atlas = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"Seagull"];
    Seagull *seagull = [Seagull spriteNodeWithTexture:[atlas textureNamed:@"Seagull1"]];

    // seagull.size = CGSizeMake(156.8, 115.4);
    // May be set scale of seagull is better? like:
    seagull.scale = 2.0;

    NSArray *flyFrames = @[[atlas textureNamed:@"Seagull1"],
                           [atlas textureNamed:@"Seagull2"]];
    SKAction *flyAnimation = [SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction animateWithTextures:flyFrames timePerFrame:0.15 resize:NO restore:NO]];

    [seagull runAction:flyAnimation];

    return seagull;
}
```

Call the class method in **GameScene**,

```
- (void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view
{
    Seagull *seagull = [Seagull spawnSeagull];
    seagull.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
    [self addChild:seagull];
}
```

Find more sample code in [this Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SpriteKit_Physics_Collisions/Listings/SpriteKit_Physics_Collisions_APLShipSprite_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013390-SpriteKit_Physics_Collisions_APLShipSprite_m-DontLinkElementID_7), how it creates `shipSprite` will help.

Comment: Thank you for your clear response @WangYudong! But, when do you use init?

Comment: @Nielsapp In `spawnSeagull`, `spriteNodeWithTexture` actually did the `init` work for you, so no need to use `init` here.